# Phone Number String to int

Tags: java, string, integer, range

Say I have the following variables:

```
String start = "02071231234"; 
String end = "02071231237"; 
List<String> numbersFromStartToEnd = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What's the best way to store: "02071231234", "02071231235", "02071231236", "02071231237" in `numbersFromStartToEnd`.

I tried changing the `String` to `int` and hoped to use a loop to create a list of Strings:

```
int startInt = Integer.parseInt(start);
```

but I'm getting

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "02885449730"
```

I guess it's because the number has a leading zero.

Comment: Nope, it's because that number is too large for an `Integer`.

Comment: @Nambari: No, `Integer.parseInt("0123")` returns `123` without a problem.

Comment: If it's too large to parse, try Long.parseLong(...)

Comment: @jlordo: Correct, my mistake, there is another issue with using leading 0 with escape literal I guess(which treats as octal). I was confused.

Comment: There's most likely a better way to go about this. Storing a phone number as an `int` (or `long` or whatever numeric) is asking for weird bugs.

Comment: so how do i return it as int/any numeric parameters with leading zero?

Comment: Integer, long and BigInteger are all the wrong data structure for a phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that any response is an actual solution. I created a small bit of code which gives the result (`["02071231234", "02071231235", "02071231236", "02071231237"]`) you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String start = "02071231234";
    String end = "02071231237";
    String leadingZeros = "";
    List<String> numbersFromStartToEnd = new ArrayList<String>();

    // get leading zeros (makes the assumption that all numbers will have same qty of leading zeros)
    for(char digit : start.toCharArray()) {
        if(digit != '0') { break; }
        leadingZeros += "0";
    }

    // set up your BigInts
    BigInteger s = new BigInteger(start);
    BigInteger e = new BigInteger(end);
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");

    // collect all numbers from start to end (adding on any leading zeros)
    while (s.compareTo(e) <= 0) {
        numbersFromStartToEnd.add(leadingZeros + s.toString());
        s = s.add(one);
    }

    // print the result
    for(String string: numbersFromStartToEnd) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm i agree.. all the answers help me. but i guess your one actually answers what i wanted. thank you

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the leading zero, see:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("0123");
System.out.println(x); // prints 123
```

The problem is that your number is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

If I were you, I'd store the phone number either as a string, or a custom `PhoneNumber` class with fields like `country code`, `area code`, `number` and so on.

---

Update: Here's how you can check if one *number* is between two other *numbers*, provided that your strings **only** consist of digits:

```
    String start   = "02071231234"; 
    String end     = "02071231237";
    String toCheck = "02071231235";
    if (start.compareTo(toCheck) < 0 && end.compareTo(toCheck) > 0) {
        System.out.println("toCheck is between start and end");
    } else {
        System.out.println("toCheck is NOT between start and end");
    }
```

Comment: oh. so how do i go about getting the numbers in between variables: "start" and "end"

Comment: @obsessiveCookie: as long as your phone number strings contain nothing besides digits, you can use the `compareTo()` method of `String`.

Comment: Sorry. How would compareTo() help get the numbers in between? Please give example

Comment: @obsessiveCookie: Almost the same way as you would do it with an `int`.

Comment: @obsessiveCookie: I think now I understand your question. This won't help you generate the strings/numbers you are looking for, it will only verify them. You're still on your own generating them.

Comment: Its fine. I only wanted to generate it to see if a certain string is between the 2 numbers. so you helped me loads. Sorry noob at programming at the moment, so my solution is so long winded than it should be XD

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your number is larger than max possible integer value

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
```

Use a `BigInteger` like this

```
BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger("my String");
```

Then you can still just do `myBigInt + 1` to get the next

or if you do trim the leading zero you should be able to use `Integer` as long as your number does not go above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`